# How to rotate a caret using css on click

Tags: css, reactjs

I am adding a caret to the end of a react bootstrap accordion.

```
.accordion>.card>.card-header:after {
    content: "";
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    border-right: 2px solid;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    float: right;
    margin-top: 6px; 
}
```

I noticed when I click on it, it has a class called 'collapse' which quickly changes to 'collapsing' and then 'collapse show'.

So, I wanted to try and rotate the caret when it is on 'collapsing' but not sure if this is possible.

This doesn't work because it rotates the actual 'collapsing' class instead of the caret created by the pseudo class

```
.collapsing {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: all ease-out 0.4s;
 }
```

jsx

```
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
          {faqs.map((faq) => (
            <Card key={faq._id}>
              <Accordion.Toggle
                as={Card.Header}
                eventKey={faq._id}
              >
                <strong>{faq.question}</strong>
              </Accordion.Toggle>
              <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={faq._id}>
                <Card.Body>{faq.answer}</Card.Body>
              </Accordion.Collapse>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </Accordion>
```

Can this be done with just CSS or am I going to have to use react state to manage this?

**EDIT:**

I tried using state but what happens now is that the caret changes for ALL items instead of just the one I clicked on

```
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
  };
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
          {faqs.map((faq) => (
            <Card key={faq._id}>
              <Accordion.Toggle
                as={Card.Header}
                eventKey={faq._id}
                onClick={handleToggle}
              >
                <strong>
                  {faq.question}
                  <div
                    className={isActive ? "arrow down" : "arrow right"}
                  ></div>
                </strong>
              </Accordion.Toggle>
              <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={faq._id}>
                <Card.Body>{faq.answer}</Card.Body>
              </Accordion.Collapse>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </Accordion>
```

New CSS:

```
.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  float: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could change your handleToggle function and pass the event parameter that will match the faq._id with the one that is clicked and trigger the classes only on that element. You could try something in this fashion.

```
const handleToggle = (e) => ( if (e.target.id === faq._id) setActive(!isActive));
```